how to initiate a github repo online using a maven archetype
Wondering whether possible to initiate a GitHub repo for Java/Maven project using a Maven Archetype just by clicking a button on a GitHub page. So, the workflow would be like this:

click a Create Project button

enter Maven project's groupId:artifactId:version (GAV)

then a codespace launches with the new project in it, ready to be pushed
or even better, the repository is just created :)


Maybe, as a generalization, the user should be asked for archetype GAV.
